# Python requests - saving cookie for later url usage

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I been trying to get a cookie and post it to a url in later use in the program, but I cant seem to get the cookie parameters to work.

Right now I have

```
response = requests.get("url")
```

But how exactly do I retrive cookies from this url and post them to a new url (the same cookies). The tutorial in requests is somewhat vague on the topic and gives examples I cannot test. Hope someone can help with further examples.

This is python 2.7 btw.

Answer (score 15):

You want to use a [session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```
s = requests.session()

response = s.get('url')
```

You use the session just like the `requests` module (it has the same methods), but it'll retain cookies for you and send them along on future requests.